# Any tool that can denote the place of stress on words?

Tags: word-stress

Is there any tool that can add the location of words' stress to an English passage? So I can learn and practice word stress in sentences?

I mean for example you type (or paste) "New year firework was fabulous." and the app should return "The new year 'firework was 'fabulous.".

Comment: It would have to do a grammar parse to decide how to put stress in "If you de'sert, you will be left in the 'desert."

Comment: I don't believe recommending tools are particularly on-topic here. But in general, I'd suggest listening to these phrases being used by native speakers to learn the idiomatic stresses. That said, it's worth remembering that there are 1000s of "native english" accents and each places stresses in different places, so there is no single most-correct way to pronounce the sentence. You may be overthinking this and worrying too much about something that nobody will notice.

Comment: I'm afraid it would be quite impossible as what words you stress depend on what you intend to emphasize, and that is only known from context. You could say *The New Years fireworks 'were fabulous*, for instance, you're making the point that they are no longer fabulous or that whatever you are currently experiencing is not fabulous. *The New Years fire'works were fabulous* suggests that something else related to or staying with *fire* at the New Year (perhaps the fire boat show) did not impress.

Comment: Please do not confuse a stress on a word with what is generally known as sentence intonation. Sentences have intonation. Words have a tonic accent or stress. Those are two separate things, in fact.